# Le « r » français et le [ɻ] américain

Tags: anglais, phonétique

Le phonème français que représente la lettre « r » est, la plupart du temps, prononcé [ʁ] ou [ʀ]. L'anglais américain a pour sa part le son [ɻ] qui est très différent du « r » français et dont le seul lien avec ce dernier semble être la façon dont on l'écrit.

Cependant, un Français qui entend [ɻ] l'analysera comme représentant le même phonème. Si un Américain prononce mal le « r » français, cela ne pose aucun problème pour la compréhension. Mais si on remplace le « r » par une autre consonne, ça risque d'être plus difficile. Ce phénomène résulte-t-il d'une similitude quelconque entre [ɻ] et [ʁ] que moi je n'entends pas?

Comment: La question est intéressante. On peut également se demander si c'est le même phénomène qui fait que beaucoup de français transforment par manque de pratique le /ð/ des anglophones (le "th" de *this* par exemple) en un approximatif /z/ voire simplement /d/ ? Est-ce que cela nuit à la compréhension des anglophones ?

Answer (score 9):

Je vois deux niveaux de réponse possible :

1. Dans le cas de [ɻ] vs [ʁ] : Tout d'abord, [ɻ] n'est la prononciation de la lettre R que dans [certains dialectes américains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phonology). Dans la *Received Pronunciation*, par exemple, on prononce plutôt [ɹ], [ɾ] en anglais d'Écosse, [ʋ] en Cockney, etc. Donc, il n'y a pas un son seul pour R en anglais, pas plus qu'en français. La flexibilité de cette consonne (voir ci-dessous), qui lui est spécifique, est probablement apprise inconsciement lors de l'éducation, probablement par des cours de langue mais aussi par la rencontre avec d'autres cultures qui prononcent le R différement (espagnols, japonais, …).
2. Plus généralement, la question touche à ce qui fait le lien, ce qui caractérise les [consonnes rhotiques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotic_consonant) (i.e. les sons en “R”). Or justement, c'est une classe [très difficile à définir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotic_consonant) :

> This class of sounds is difficult to characterise phonetically; from a phonetic standpoint, there is no single articulatory correlate common to rhotic consonants. Rhotics have instead been found to carry out similar phonological functions or to have certain similar phonological features across different languages. […] **Being “R-like” is an elusive and ambiguous concept phonetically** and the same sounds that function as rhotics in some systems may pattern with fricatives, semivowels or even stops in others.

Comment: Sans parler de consonnes rhotiques, `[ɻ]` est une liquide, comme `[r]` qui est une variante libre de `/R/`, la seule autre liquide en français est `[l]`, qui existe déjà en anglais, et que les francophones confondent parfois avec `[ɻ]`. Ça ne me paraît pas absurde que les français comprennent `[ɻ]` comme un `[r]` et donc comme `/R/`.

Answer (score 4):

N'est-ce pas simplement dû au fait que les Français ont appris que "ɻ" est un "r américain"?  Comme les français actuels apprennent tous l'anglais, ils ont une bonne connaissance du vocabulaire anglais, et bien souvent même, les mots sont proches du français, permettant d'inférer l'orthographe du mot.

Un bon exemple serait sans doute le nom de l'actuel Président des USA, Barack Obama, dont tout le monde a entendu le prénom "Barack" avec son son "r" prononcé par des américains.
Il est donc aisé d'associer "ɻ]" à "r", sans qu'il y ait de similitude phonétique.
Un Français n'entendra pas le même phonème, mais associera le son à la lettre utilisée dans d'autres mots de référence.  S'il entend "a rack", il pensera à "barack", et donc à "r".

Telle est mon intuition.