# Comment prononcer le son « r » plus doucement?

Tags: prononciation

Beaucoup de gens ont des difficultés à prononcer le son « r » mais pour moi, c'est un peu le contraire. Je le prononce à tel point que ça me fait du mal (un peu) - je pensais que c'était normal jusqu'à ce que je me sois entendu parler, et c'était comme si je voulais cracher constamment. Mais quand j’essaie de le prononcer un peu plus doucement, il me semble que je prononce le « h » de l'anglais, et je me dis que je l’ai mal prononcé, voire pas du tout.

Est-ce que je le prononce avec la partie incorrecte de ma gorge ou quelque chose comme ça ? Y-a-t-il une solution ?

Answer (score 3):

Il m'est devenu apparent il y a quelque temps déjà que la situation que vous évoquez est réelle : il existe toute une plage d'allophones pour ce son et selon l'environnement phonétique, une prononciation plus ou moins dure sera utilisée (elle varie aussi avec le locuteur); on peut remarquer qu'assez souvent les locuteurs qui parlent une variété du français métropolitain (Belges, Suisses, Canadiens, …) ont tendance à avoir une prononciation plus dure encore.

Voici par exemple la prononciation de « rat » ([rat](https://septiemeartetdemi.com/2020/07/06/histoire-prononciation-evolution-tout-sur-le-r-francais/)) et de « riz » (seconde possibilité pour « rat », la première étant une variante de r roulé qui n'est pas habituelle de nos jours). Dans les deux cas la prononciation comporte une composante de bruit (l'effet de craché que vous mentionnez) et elle est plus importante dans la prononciation de « rat ». Ces prononciations sont courantes de nos jours et elles peuvent même avoir assez souvent une composante de bruit plus importante encore. Cependant, cette composante peut aussi être totalement éliminée pour cet environnement phonétique (première lettre du mot). Remarquez [ici](https://apprendre.tv5monde.com/en/aides/pronunciation-r-sound) comment un même locuteur peut introduire dans sa prononciation des composantes de bruit très différentes en importance (Ri Ri Ri Ra Ra Ra).  Néanmoins, éliminer complètement cette composante ne doit pas se traduire par une aspiration (qui est en réalité une exhalation) et donc par un h anglais. J'ai personnellement une grande préférence pour cet allophone sans bruit, bien que la forte influence du parler contemporain auquel je suis exposé résulte parfois en mon utilisation de l'allophone « bruyant » alors que je ne le voudrais pas.
Vous allez trouver cette variante sans bruit maintenant dans le mot « [reine](https://septiemeartetdemi.com/2020/07/06/histoire-prononciation-evolution-tout-sur-le-r-francais/) ». La turbulence disparait, c'est à dire que le bruit disparait et le r devient une quasi voyelle (semi-voyelle). Vous pouvez remarquer qu'il n'y a aucune aspiration.

Donné un environnement phonétique particulier, la prononciation de r a une forte tendance a conserver une composante de « bruit ».

> ([réf.](https://septiemeartetdemi.com/2020/07/06/histoire-prononciation-evolution-tout-sur-le-r-francais/)) le R devient généralement [χ] après /p/, /t/ ou /k/ : prononcez « proie », « trois » et « croix » et vous vous rendrez normalement compte qu’il sonne plus fort que dans « roi ».

Essayer la prononciation de [croix](https://septiemeartetdemi.com/2020/07/06/histoire-prononciation-evolution-tout-sur-le-r-francais/) (proie, trois), par exemple.  Dans cet environnement particulier une composante de bruit semble inévitable (essayer les prononciations « roi » et « trois » en successions plus ou moins rapide pour constater la plus grande facilité qui existe pour minimiser le bruit de la prononciation du r de « roi ».

Il n'y a apparemment aucune possibilité d'élimination du bruit pour des r en position finale, comme dans  celle de « [ministre](https://septiemeartetdemi.com/2020/07/06/histoire-prononciation-evolution-tout-sur-le-r-francais/) » par exemple.

Comment: Certaines prononciation très relâchées et peu élégantes selon moi n'hésitent pas à éliminer carrément le "re" final: monsieur le minist', rien à perd', rien à fout',...

Comment: @LaurentS. On arrive pourtant à trouver certaines de ces prononciations acceptables, par exemple "quatre-quart" : — Prononc. et Orth.: [katʀ əka:ʀ]. Cour. [katka:ʀ]— (https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/dictionnaire/definition/quatre-quarts)

Comment: En effet... par ailleurs merci de m'avoir fait sourire en réalisant que j'avais passé la dernière minute à prononcer "riz" et "rat" tout seul à haute voix comme unbidiit pour me rendre compte de la différence de son :-)

Comment: @LaurentS. Je suppose que c'est « un bidiit », mais ce n'est toujours pas suffisant… bidet ? un âne? Je n'arrive pas à deviner.

Comment: Mon correcteur a fait des siennes... je voulais écrire "comme un idiot" mais ne pensais pas illustrer si bien mon propos ;-)

Comment: @LaurentS. La réduction des consonnes finales n'a rien à voir avec la prononciation du son « r » de la question. Par ailleurs ces réductions sont courantes en français du [Québec](https://www.erudit.org/fr/revues/cl/1973-n3-cl3105/800025ar.pdf). Elles ne seront jamais aussi inélégantes que d'avoir constamment recours à une langue germanique pour s'exprimer en français, selon moi.

Comment: Mon commentaire s'appliquait uniquement au dernier paragraphe de la réponse. Mon intention n'était nullement de heurter la sensibilité des uns et des autres. Le fait est que de ce côté de l'Atlantique cela n'est pas si courant...

Comment: Ce n'est pas courant et ce n'est pas considéré comme souhaitable, ni à voir avec indulgence; ces tendances portent à mon avis le germe de la pidginisation.

Answer (score 2):

D'après tes explications, tu prononces le *R* comme un *ch* de l'écossais *lo**ch***, de l'allemand Ba**ch** ou comme l'arabe *Kh* de ***Kh**aled*.

C'est bien plutôt comme ça qu'il est prononcé par la majorité des français (consonne [fricative](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_fricative#:%7E:text=En%20phon%C3%A9tique%20articulatoire%2C%20une%20consonne,le%20cas%20pour%20les%20occlusives.) [uvulaire](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_uvulaire)), mais, sauf en position finale, le son est normalement sonore ([voisé](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voisement)) alors que le tien est sourd (sans vibration des cordes vocales), ce qui donne cette impression de cracher.

Le prononcer ainsi ne pose pas de problème de compréhension, ces deux consonnes étant perçues comme équivalentes (allophones).

Puisque la différence tient au voisement, il suffirait que tu fasses vibrer tes cordes vocales lorsque tu prononces un *R* pour que ce dernier corresponde à la prononciation la plus courante.

Tu peux percevoir la différence en comparant d'autres consonnes voisées ou non:

```
+---------+------------+
| Voisée  | Non voisée |
+---------+------------+
|    b    |     p      | 
+---------+------------+
|    d    |     t      | 
+---------+------------+
|    g    |     k      | 
+---------+------------+
|    z    |     s      | 
+---------+------------+
```

Si tu mets ta main sur ta gorge, tu sens les vibrations des cordes vocales dans le premier cas uniquement. Essaie de les faire vibrer quand tu prononces un *R* et ce sera gagné.

Si tu n'y arrives pas facilement, ne t'inquiètes pas. Le *R* est probablement la lettre qui présente le plus de variations régionales en français. On entend encore des *R* roulés à l'italienne ou l'espagnole ou des *R* prononcés comme un *w* anglais (caramel → « *caouamel* ») en français antillais, voire pas prononcés du tout.

Voir aussi:

- [À quel point est-il acceptable d'utiliser le « r » comme en espagnol au lieu du « r » français?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/20098)
- [Trilled / Rolled "R"s?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7575)
- [Le « r » français et le [ɻ] américain](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/697)
- [La Marseillaise : les /r/, couplets usuels ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14396)
- [D'où vient le R uvulaire du français ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/340)
- [Pronunciation of 'r' at the end of a word](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/22678)
- [Étymologie de « grasseyer » : le [ʁ] est gras ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17466)